# Combine my static code to my dynamic code. (Avoid matching player with the same name)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making a matchmaking system where 2 players of the same level will be matched. The snippet I provided is a static code, it means that the data is from the "const players" that I just created. It is not from the database. In this function, it does not match players with the same name. Players with the same name are just stored in the "unmatched players". The question is, how can i combine my static code and my dynamic code to achieve the player with the same name shouldn't be matched?. Thank you in advance

[image]

javascript (This is my static code. What i mean by static code is that I'm getting my players from "const players". It is not from database. I want to combine this code with my dynamic code below)

```js
 //I'm getting my data from const players
const players = Array.from({ length: 18 }, (v,k) => ( { level: Math.floor(k / 6) + 1, player: `test-${Math.floor(k/2)+1}` }));

// this function removes duplicates (Player who has the same name)
function removeDuplicates(players) {
   return Object.values(players.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
       acc[curr.player] = acc[curr.player] || curr;
       return acc;
   }, {}))
}

 //This function combine players in 1 array if they have the same level (This alone is working with my dynamic code below 
const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level]) {
      const levelArr = acc[curr.level];
      const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
      if (last.length === 2) {
        levelArr.push([curr])
      } else {
        last.push(curr)
      }
    } else {
      acc[curr.level] = [
        [curr]
      ];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
};




const uniquePlayers = removeDuplicates(players);


const matched = Object.values(combine(uniquePlayers)).flatMap(a => a.filter(x => x.length === 2));
const unmatched = Object.values(combine(uniquePlayers)).flatMap(a => a.filter(x => x.length === 1));
console.log("Matched players:", matched);
console.log("Unmatched players:", unmatched);
```

// This is my script that matches players. (Dynamic codes meaning i'm fetching the data from the Database) The problem is, it is still matching the players with the same name. It shouldn't be like that. The player with the same player name should be stored in the waiting list array.
script ajax:

```
let ajaxResult = []; // the pushed data will be saved here
let save_method;
let table;
let base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
let result = [];
var html = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    //datatables
    table = $("#entry_list1").DataTable({


        processing: false,
        serverSide: true,
        order: [],
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        info: false,

        ajax: {
            url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/fetch')?>",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",

             success: function(data) {

                result = combine(data.data2);
                console.log(result)
                var keys = Object.keys(result)
                
                
                
                
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {
    val.forEach(function(value, index) {

      var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
      var players = index == 0 ? "playerM[]" : "playerW[]"
      var levels = index == 0 ? "levelM[]" : "levelW[]"
      html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                 <input type="text" name="${players}" value="${value.player}">
                 <input type="text" name="${levels}" value="${value.level}">
                 `
    })
  })
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

                
               
              
                

            },
        },

        "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0], //first column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
            {
                "targets": [-1], //last column
                "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },

        ],
    });
});
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your question?

Comment: I tried to replace the unction removeDuplicates(players) with 
function removeDuplicates(result) {  

I did that because i'm fetching my data in my result after success of my ajax. But it's not working.

I replaced this one const uniquePlayers = removeDuplicates(players); with  

const uniquePlayers = removeDuplicates(result);

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing. "Not working" is a pretty broad description, please explain that further, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What is not working with the given code?

Comment: My target is to combine the static code with my dynamic code. The static code does not match the player with the same name, whereas the dynamic code. It matches the player with the same name. My target is, how can I avoid the same player name in matching?

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that? What exactly do you mean by "static" and "dynamic" code? What's the difference between them? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it - don't use the comment section for important stuff

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it. It's now solved.

```
// This code is for removing duplicates
function removeDuplicates(result) {
   return Object.values(result.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
       acc[curr.player] = acc[curr.player] || curr;
       return acc;
   }, {}))
}

const uniquePlayers = removeDuplicates(result); // I passed my result variable here from my ajax script




                 
                result = combine(removeDuplicates(data.data2)); //I added the remove duplicate function here so that the player that has the same name shouldn't be matched. 
                
                console.log(result)
                
                var keys = Object.keys(result)
```